# Xcode 4 debugger code completion

Tags: objective-c, xcode

First off, it is nice that they are trying to get code completion on the gdb command prompt in Xcode 4.  But in its current state, it makes using the command prompt to investigate objective c objects nearly impossible - when I'm typing, it autocompletes the word to something I didn't want, and there is no way to undo this without manually selecting the text and removing it, then starting over.

I should probably file a bug with apple for this, but in the meantime, does anyone have a work around for this (like say, turning off auto-completion for the debugger *without* turning it off for code editing - I like auto-completion in obj-c because method names are so long :).

Comment: Someone else has asked this same question in another more detailed manner [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220682/how-to-make-xcode-4-4-debug-console-use-a-popup-for-autocomplete) .  Code Sense in the debugger is a beautiful solution to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I've come to solving this incredibly annoying problem is to turn off automatic code completion in general (Preferences > Text Editing > Suggest Completions While Typing) and then hit **esc** whenever I actually do want code completion.

Comment: Hm, not the best solution for long term (of course that is for apple to finish their auto-completion implementation! :), but it does the trick when I have a long debugging session..