# How can I disable gdb variable name auto-complete in Xcode 4 console?

Tags: xcode4, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you stop the XCode debugger from autocompleting without options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195691/how-do-you-stop-the-xcode-debugger-from-autocompleting-without-options)

**GDB** in Xcode 4 auto-completes variable names in console. It works fine most of the time, not always. Sometimes it auto-completes with garbage or auto-completes too quickly or too slowly. I got tired of wasting time fixing wrong auto-completions.

I'd like to disable it or ideally auto-complete **only with ESC key**, never automatically.

Is there some hidden preference in Xcode or some obscure setting in GDB for this purpose?

Comment: This problem is solved in another thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195691/how-do-you-stop-the-xcode-debugger-from-autocompleting