# How to make Xcode 4.4 debug console use a popup for autocomplete?

Tags: debugging, autocomplete, xcode4.4, codesense

I am using Xcode Version 4.4.1 (4F1003) on OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.1

---

Say you are debugging in Xcode, and you stop at a breakpoint.

Then you go to the debug console prompt and start typing `po loc`...

For me, one of two things will happen:

1.) The console will display a popup with options (the same way autocomplete works in the main text editing window)

[image: autocomplete popup]

or

2.) The console will simply automatically autocomplete to the first thing it finds.  For example `po localeconv()`.  Even though I was going to type `po locationForAPI`.

---

As far as I can tell, it is random as to when Xcode will behave as 1 and when it will behave as 2.

It turns out that 2 is not very useful at all ([here are people trying to turn this functionality off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7195691/888507)).

---

But, behavior 1 is very useful!

Thus, my question:
**Does anyone know how to force Xcode to use behavior 1 and not behavior 2?**

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431501/xcode-4-code-sense-is-not-working?

Comment: This is a terrific question.  When it did it for me for like 10 minutes the other day it was like a debugging revelation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  Restart Xcode
Xcode always starts in the good behavior and then switches to the bad behavior at some point.

(The classic "Delete Derived Data" doesn't work in this situation)